# ATL/COM: Why does CComSafeArray::GetCount() throw an exception for an empty array?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I'm using the ATL [CComSafeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xzbsee8.aspx) class, but it seems that `GetCount()` will throw an exception if the array is empty, for example this code throws an exception:

```
CComSafeArray<MyStruct> array;
// array.Add(item); // There won't be an exception if I uncomment this line.
array.GetCount();
```

This is the code of the constructor and GetCount() (from ATL sources):

```
CComSafeArray() throw() : m_psa(NULL)
{
}
ULONG GetCount(UINT uDim = 0) const
{
    ATLASSUME(m_psa != NULL);
    ATLASSERT(uDim < GetDimensions());
    LONG lLBound, lUBound;
    HRESULT hRes = SafeArrayGetLBound(m_psa, uDim+1, &lLBound);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));
    if(FAILED(hRes))
        AtlThrow(hRes);
    hRes = SafeArrayGetUBound(m_psa, uDim+1, &lUBound);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));
    if(FAILED(hRes))
        AtlThrow(hRes);
    return (lUBound - lLBound + 1);
}
```

As you can see, the constructor gives a NULL value to `m_psa`, and in `GetCount()`, this causes `SafeArrayGetLBound()` to return an error HRESULT, which causes AtlThrow() to be called.

But I don't understand why `GetCount()` should throw an exception if the array is empty. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Aside: Why are the microsoft libraries filled with boilerplate looking unreadable?

Comment: That's their style! :)

Comment: What `Count` you actually expected for an undefined array?

Comment: Zero, like in `std::vector`.

Comment: You have an uninitialized array.  Kaboom.  Calling Add() is a workaround of sorts but it is drastically inefficient, every Add() call needs to resize the array.  You ought to specify the bounds that you need.  Do keep in mind that an array is *not* a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unbound wrapper for a SAFEARRAY, not an empty array.

If you want an empty SAFEARRAY you can declare one:

```
CComSafeArray<MyStruct> array((ULONG)0);
```

Comment: Yeah, SAFEARRAY is something of a misnomer. Don't know why they wouldn't return zero there. Likewise, why wouldn't the default constructor for CComSafeArray declare an empty one? Maybe on the Visual Basic side the only way to distinguish the empty ones from the null ones would be the exceptions.